# Adding angular material theme into ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-material2

How can I get angular material theme included in my app.

I tried @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in variable.scss and tried using the path in styleUrls of my app module as well. Tried using '../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' as well.

In all the cases browser is giving 404

Comment: Import the material files into your app.scss. Make sure your path is correct, because this is the way to do it. Otherwise include it in your index.html (dirty imo)

Comment: I tried importing in app.scss and is still giving me 404. However, when i changed the extension for the prebuilt theme to scss and imported with a sass.config update, it worked for me. css files alone seem to be having the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is due to the configuration present in ionic app-scripts which doesn't include other node_modules paths. To fix this create a file

> sass.config.json in config folder

with the below contents

```
// cross verify with node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/sass.config.js

module.exports = {

    /**
     * includePaths: Used by node-sass for additional
     * paths to search for sass imports by just name.
     */
    includePaths: [
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
    'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',

    'PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE'
  ]

};
```

Update the file

> package.json

and add the below

```
"config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
},
```

This would override the default app-script config for what is provided.

Answer (score 1):

To include the material css the following worked for me:

**First** create file config/sass.config.json

**Second** Enter the following:

```
// cross verify with node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/sass.config.js

module.exports = {

  /**
  * includePaths: Used by node-sass for additional
  * paths to search for sass imports by just name.
  */
  includePaths: [
  'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
  'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
  'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',

  'node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes'
  ],

  includeFiles: [
    /\.(s?(c|a)ss)$/i
  ],

  excludeFiles: [
    // /\.(wp|ios|md).(scss)$/i
  ],

};
```

**Third** in packages.json at the bottom (still inside the last curly bracket) add

```
"config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
},
```

**Fourth** run

```
ionic serve
```

### Explenation

The inlcudeFiles part is to be able to also include css (as the prebuild angular-material indigo-pink is an css and not an scss file.

The exclude files excludes a lot of ionic-css. I had the feeling some of the default ionic theme interferes with angular-material css, so I put this. BUT: Only put these lines if you are not planning to use the default  components.

You can get rid of more default css such as ionicons as explained here https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/#Remove_ionicons

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for this case once that you want to import a *CSS file* (not a SCSS) you need to provide *just the file name* on `@import` *without the extension*. If you provide the .css extension the `@import` will be compiled to CSS `@import` rule as stated on [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).

So if you include `node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes` in your `includePaths` your `app.scss` will be something like this:

```
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/


// App Global Sass
// --------------------------------------------------
// Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These
// styles are for the entire app and not just one component.
// Additionally, this file can be also used as an entry point
// to import other Sass files to be included in the output CSS.
//
// Shared Sass variables, which can be used to adjust Ionic's
// default Sass variables, belong in "theme/variables.scss".
//
// To declare rules for a specific mode, create a child rule
// for the .md, .ios, or .wp mode classes. The mode class is
// automatically applied to the <body> element in the app.

@import "indigo-pink"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this steps as mention on the website, This will add angular material in your ionic project succesfully.

https://www.freakyjolly.com/use-angular-material-in-ionic-3/

after that add

```
  <link href="assets/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

to index.html

Thank you.