# Angular-material button does not render in ionic 3 application

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-material

I am trying to use angular-material controls in my Ionic 3 application. I have installed @angular/material, @angular/cdk and @angular/animation packages. I have imported the BrowserAnimationModule and MatButtonModule in app.module.ts. I am using the indigo-pink.css theme and it is loading fine. The material button renders but shows no text. I have examined the button style in the dev console of the browser and see nothing out of place. Image below. What am I missing?

[image]

```html
<ion-content>
    <button mat-raised-button>I am here!</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to  include material theme see this [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592222/adding-angular-material-theme-into-ionic-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding angular material theme into ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592222/adding-angular-material-theme-into-ionic-3)

Comment: That didn't help.