# Angular Material Design with ionic 3 : theme colour not works

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, angular-material, hybrid-mobile-app

I just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055932/3073010) to integrate Angular Material into the Ionic 3 app. Everything is fine. I can include all the material element in ionic app now but the theme colour is not working.

Below is my package.json configuration:

```
 "@angular/animations": "5.2.4",
 "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
 .
 .
 "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
 "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
 "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
 "@angular/material": "5.2.4",
 .
 .
 "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
 "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
 "ionicons": "3.0.0",
```

[image: seeing this result when i run 'ionic serve']

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in styles.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

and also in pollyfills.ts add

```
import 'hammerjs';
```